# How can include two types of quotes in a string in php?

Tags: php

I need to build the following string:

```
#<tr class="[^"]*">
<td><div class="grid_content sno"><span>[^"]*</span></div></td>
<td>
<center>
<div class="grid_content2 sno">
<span>
<img src="https://seriesblanco.com/banderas/es.png">
</span>
</div>
<center>
</td>
<td>
<div class="grid_content sno">
<span>
<a href="(.*?)" target="_blank">
<img src='/servidores/powvideo.jpg' width='[^"]*' height='[^"]*' /></a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="grid_content sno"><span>[^"]*</span>
</td>
<td>
<div class="grid_content sno"><span>[^"]*</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>#
```

As you can see it has `""` and `''` quotes and I'm finding impossible to build a string like `$string = *codeabove*` because it closes itself if I use one kind of quote or another, is there another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could excape a caracter with '\'
so for example

```
$string = 'theString\''
```

Comment: so this would work?: `$string = "<img src=\"\url\"\>";`

Comment: @IsmaelQuirantes i thint the result you want is <img src="url"> so you have to write $string = "<img src=\"url\">";

Comment: `echo"<img src=\"url\">";` works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without escaping and more elegant:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOD
Example of string 
using 'both' types 
of "quotes" with 
heredoc sintax.
EOD;

echo $str;
```

Will print:

```
Example of string 
using 'both' types 
of "quotes" with 
heredoc sintax.
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the quote character is one solution. In simple cases it is the easiest thing to do.

But sometimes it is much easier to simply [slip out of HTML and use the PHP interpreter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) instead. There is no performance hit for do so. Depending on the circumstances it leads to code that's easier to read and write. For instance...

```
<?php
$str = '[^"]*';
?>
<div class="grid_content sno"><span><?= $str; ?></span></div>
```

Admittedly a simple case where simply escaping one quote character is easy. But consider a more complicated example.

```
<?php
$selected = $some_value;
if($expression == true): ?>
    <div class="somecss">
        <select>
            <?php foreach($options as $key => $value): ?>
                <option value='<?= $key; ?>'
                        <?php if($key === $selected) : ?> selected = "selected"<?php endif; ?>
                        ><?= $value; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<?php else: //$expression is false ?>
    <div class="error">No options available</div>
<?php endif; ?>
More HTML here
```